# How to say Thanks for confirming? "Gracias por confirmar" or "Gracias por haber confirmado"?

Tags: traducción, gramática, tiempos-verbales, preguntas, cortesía

What is the correct translation of **"Thanks for confirming"**?

> Gracias por confirmar (futuro)

or

> Gracias por haber confirmado (pasado)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, yes, in the past it should be *gracias por **haber confirmado***, but that doesn't mean you won't hear *gracias por confirmar* with high frequency with that meaning.

For another example, you'll hear *gracias por venir* all the time, even though, presumably, if they've already arrived at your house/party/event/place/shindig, you're thanking them for *having* coming over (they're not on their way by the time you're thanking them).  Context normally makes that pretty clear, but when it doesn't, using the *infinitivo compuesto* lets us clearly indicate a prior action.

If you feel the need to strictly distinguish and force a future interpretation, in your specific example (not necessarily applicable to all verbs) you might say *gracias por confirmar con antelación / de antemano* or similar to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Also, "Gracias por la confirmación" When you refer to a letter.