# "Gracias por venir" y "gracias por haber venido"

Tags: gramática, infinitivo

¿Son equivalentes estas expresiones?

He visto que la construcción con infinitivo se usa intercambiablemente con la de *haber + pasado participio*.

Comment: Estoy segurísimo de que esta pregunta ya se ha preguntado (porque recuerdo contestándola), pero de momento no la encuentro.

Comment: Ah, aquí está: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8170/how-to-say-thanks-for-confirming

Answer (score 2):

Sí, son prácticamente equivalentes.

La forma "haber + participio" (como *haber venido*) es lo que se llama un **infinitivo compuesto**. Suele (aunque no siempre) indicar anterioridad a un momento dado. No hay mucha diferencia entre:

> Gracias por haber venido // Gracias por venir
>
> Gracias a ti por haberme invitado // Gracias por invitarme

Los usos del infinitivo compuesto son:

- Complementar al verbo principal

> Se disculpó por haber olvidado la fiesta cumpleaños
>
> Reconoció haber olvidado por completo la fiesta

- Complementar (explicar) un adjetivo

> Estaba encantado de haber ido a la fiesta
>
> Estaba contento de haber tenido tantos invitados

- Expresar anterioridad/posterioridad

> Fue a la fiesta después de haber hecho los deberes
>
> Fue de dormir después de haberse lavado los dientes

- Expresar gratitud

> Gracias por haberme ayudado
>
> Gracias por haber venido

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la diferencia está en que con *haber*, se entiende que la acción está completa, o está más remota en el tiempo.  Por ejemplo, cuando llegas a mi fiesta, te digo

> --Gracias por venir

y tú me dices

> --Gracias por invitarme.

Al otro día, si nos encontramos en el supermercado, el diálogo podría ser:

> --Gracias por organizar la fiesta.  La pasé muy bien.
>
> --Pero gracias a tí por haberme dado la idea de festejar el fin de curso.

Pero esta distinción no es muy estricta.